# AlarmManager doesn't work properly

Tags: android, background, alarmmanager

What is wrong with this code ? I don't get any errors and the code doesn't work what should i do ?

**MainActivity.java**

```
Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MyService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime,
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MapsActivity.this, 1, alertIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    createNotification(context, "Alarm", "ASDFG", "ASDF");
}

public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert) {


    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.searchicon)
                    .setContentTitle(msg)
                    .setTicker(msgAlert)
                    .setContentText(msgText);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
 }}
```

BTW I want to start Alarm and Notification on `setOnMyLocationChangeListener` which is in `MainActivity.java` class under `onCreate()` someone could help me for that to run in background ?

Comment: Have you added logs on the onReceive method to check whether it is really being called?

Comment: Wow my excuses about this problem i actually have putted `<receiver android:name=".MyService" ></receiver>` on wrong place in `AndroidManifest.xml`... Can i also ask here for the running in background `onLocationChange` ? or to post new question ?

Comment: since it is a new question, it is better for you to close this one (answer your own question with the fix for the problem) and open another.

Answer (score 0):

My excuses about this problem i actually have putted `<receiver android:name=".MyService" ></receiver>` on wrong place in `AndroidManifest.xml` It needs to be inside `<application></application>` tag.